# httpOnly cookie is being sent with the response but is not being stored in the browser cookies

Tags: cookies, next.js, jwt, nestjs

Here is the Nestjs service that sends the cookie

```
async loginSeller(loginSellerInput: LoginSellerInput, ctx: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
      loginSellerInput.email,
      loginSellerInput.password,
    );
    if (!user) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Email or password are invalid`);
    } else {
      const seller = await this.sellerModel.findOne({
        email: loginSellerInput.email,
      });
      seller.last_connected = new Date();
      seller.save();
      const tokens = await this.authService.generateUserCredentials(user);
      const serialised = serialize('OursiteJWT', tokens.access_token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        sameSite: 'strict',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        path: '/',
      });
      await this.usersService.updateRtHash(user.id, tokens.refresh_token);
      return tokens;
    }
  }
```

And here is my apollo config in the client side (using nextjs):

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
    credentials: "same-origin",
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    // const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            // authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
        },
    };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

// const client = new ApolloClient({
//  uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
//  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
// });

export default client;
```

This is the proof that the cookie is actually being sent but when going to application in the dev tools under cookies nothing shows up!
[image]

I have tried enabling cors in the main.ts in nestjs
And tried changing apollo client config with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the cookie is a **samesite=strict**, and **secure**, that cookie will only be accepted and sent by the browser over HTTPS, not HTTP.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: Thanks for you response, I did what you suggested:
`sameSite: 'none'`
`secure: false`

But the problem is still persisting as I am getting the cookie in the response but it's not being set in the browser

Comment: You can't set a cookie with samesite=none, and not secure, browsers require that the cookie must set over HTTPS for samesite=none to work. You can always try with setting it to Lax.

Comment: `sameSite: 'lax'` and `secure: true` worked for me... Thanks